# Verifying which model of HP Chromebook will allow for Arch installation?

Tags: linux, arch-linux, system-installation, chrome-book

New to Arch and trying to make sense of this chart:

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Chrome_OS_devices/Chromebook

I have the HP Chromebook 14 G3 (Oct 2014) with a 2.1 GHz Nvidia Tegra K1

The chart says: **Unavailable
on ARM  Unsupported by
Arch Linux ARM**

Does that mean I'm unable to install Arch on this machine? What exactly does this mean?

Answer (score 0):

[ArchLinux](https://archlinux.org) *only* supports `IA-32` and `x86_64`. [ArchLinuxARM](https://archlinuxarm.org) (ALARM for short), which is a *separate*, derivative distribution from ArchLinux, does not officially support your machine.

It may, however, be in the ALARM [Community Supported](http://archlinuxarm.org/forum/viewforum.php?f=27) category.

So, can you install Arch on *any* ARM-based machine? No. Can you install ALARM on your machine? possibly (but it will not be officially supported).